# no visible @interface for UIAlertView declears the selector

Tags: ios

it says

> no visible @interface for UIAlertView declears the selector
>   'initWithTtile:message....

this is what i have-

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@, here is your error", [error description]] delegate: nil cancelbuttonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Comment: @Alexander That has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Method names are case sensitive. Double check your spelling. And always make use of Xcode method name completion. It avoids simple errors like this.

Comment: checlk my answer really helpful to you...

Comment: @JitendraDeore There is no need to post a comment telling the OP to check your answer. The answer is enough.

Comment: @rmaddy that's right... I'm so accustomed to the behavior I was referring to...

Comment: check the case of cancelButtonTitle. it is not cancelbuttonTitle. Why don't you use autocompletion/code sense ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in `cancelbuttonTitle` **B** should be in caps. Like `cancelButtonTitle`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@, here is your error", [error description]] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

It shows that because the method is incorrect

Use

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@, here is your error", [error description]]
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Comment: I think its a one line code And it doesnt need much explanation

Comment: It's a very long line and the change is very subtle.

Answer (score -1):

initWithTtle is written in your error - should be **Title** not Ttle

Comment: This doesn't tell the OP how to fix the actual code they used.

Comment: But the OP properly has `initWithTitle:` in the actual method call. That's not the problem.